# Can we define inverse of an injective function this way?

Tags: functions

Given $ f : {A} \to {B}$ is only an injective function. Can we define the inverse function $ g: B\to A $
If $g$ gives the null set when given an element that wasn't mapped to in $f$. The inverse function $g$ would still be valid as a function but we cannot define $f$ as a function if we try to map the null set to elements in $B$ .

Comment: What if $\varnothing\in A$, e.g., $A$ is some nonzero ordinal?

Comment: @user10354138 Then it won't work.

Comment: @AristotleStagiritis Actually, your $g$ would be a function **only** if $\emptyset\in A$ (or $f$ is onto), for without that you cannot define $g(x)=\emptyset$ for some $x\in B$